# Google is changing my urls in search results - Joomla3 bug

Tags: google, url, sitemap, joomla

My urls is something like

[escene.ir/component/products/تلفن-های-تحت-شبکه-مدیریتی/Escene-ES620-PEN-IP-Phone?task=view.12](http://escene.ir/component/products/%D8%AA%D9%84%D9%81%D9%86-%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%AA%D8%AD%D8%AA-%D8%B4%D8%A8%DA%A9%D9%87-%D9%85%D8%AF%DB%8C%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%AA%DB%8C/Escene-ES620-PEN-IP-Phone?task=view.12)

but when I try to search **site:escene.ir** to see the whole links of my site, the urls are like

**escene.ir/component/products?task=view.12**

There is no link like the second one in my site, And yes, I submitted a site map and there is no link like the second one in my site map, too .any idea ??

- I'm using Joomla! 3

---

### Update  :

this is a bug in Joomla! 3 and has not been fixed yet.

look at the [**@isNaN 's answer**](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/60833/google-is-changing-my-urls-in-search-results/60838?noredirect=1#60838), and this discussion : [**Joomla 3 and canonical URL**](http://joomla-seo.net/Blog/joomla-3-and-canonical-url)

Comment: What application are you using on your site?

Comment: Im using Joomla! 3

Comment: Sorry. I do not know anything about Joomla. But I am sure someone will and can answer your question. I suspect it has something to do with the application somehow.

Comment: I dont think it has anything relevant to Joomla!, Google doesn't look for application or something. the problem is the search results' urls is different to my websites urls and my sitemap urls

Comment: Okay. I will leave it to a Joomla expert. Otherwise, I would not have a clue. Sorry. I would love to help, but I have no ideas at this point.

Comment: I can't give a comprehensive answer but I do know this is related to Joomla's 'SEF' URLs and that Google isn't changing the links - those are both working links for your site. Getting Joomla to consistently use 'pretty URLs' is far more difficult than with other CMSs but you might try one of the Joomla SEF extensions to improve things. Good luck.

Comment: this was a **bug in Joomla3** and I updated my question and put a link to the discussion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your header you have a canonical link (on line 11, just under `<title>`).

It looks like this on your page:

```
<link href="http://escene.ir/component/products/?task=view.12" rel="canonical" />
```

This element tells Google your **preferred** URL for a page which has several urls to choose from. This is to prevent you from being penalized for having duplicate content. (Several url's pointing to the same page.)

--> [More info on Canonicals @ Google Webmaster Tools](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en)

Comment: I found out this is a bug inn Joomla! 3, and I fixed it.

Comment: @AlirezaFallah웃 Can you please post a link to the bug so that future readers can follow it?

Comment: @Kevin, yeah, I updated my question .

Comment: Just wanted to add that from Google's point of view, the clean, parameterized URL is generally preferred to any unnecessary URL-rewriting. If you want a nice-looking URL-line in search, use breadcrumb markup instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure Google not changed your url, because when I visited your [page(second URL)](http://escene.ir/component/products?task=view.12) it shows with that url. You have duplicate content for the same page, best thing is you have to redirect using 301(permanent redirect) to that page and also try to remove that link(if present) from XML sitemap.

Comment: As I said in my question, there is ***NO*** such link like the second one in sitemap, and my website links

Comment: @AlirezaFallah웃 google will index urls even if you not submit the sitemap

Comment: and how it gonna find it when there is no such link in my website either

Comment: I don't understand, your website have that link http://escene.ir/component/products?task=view.12 that's what I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: ok, user wont get error in that url, but I'm telling you that there is no such link nowhere in my website. where is the link ? I dont understand you

Comment: What ? this link http://escene.ir/component/products?task=view.12 is not from your website ?